# How to fetch distinct values with arel/relational algebra

Tags: distinct, relational-algebra, arel

I'm doing my best to bend my brain around arel and the relational algebra behind it, but how to represent a `SELECT DISTINCT` is consistently eluding my comprehension. Can anyone explain how to arel:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title FROM posts;
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know arel but from my reading of "Database in Depth" by C.J.Date, in relational algebra the result of a query is a set of tuples. So if arel is following this theory than distinct should be the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Post.select('DISTINCT title')`

**Update 1:**

At the time of the post, this was not available in Arel.  These days, ActiveRecord::QueryMethods has the `uniq` method (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq), so you'd want:

```
Post.select(:title).uniq
```

**Update 2:**
Looks like Arel now supports this behavior.  @maerics has the correct answer.  I'd delete this if it wasn't the accepted answer.

Comment: Not exactly algebraic, but hard to argue with it's efficiency ;-)

Comment: There is a fatal problem with this approach: if you have more than one scope with a select statement, chaining them together can cause invalid SQL.

Comment: This is not AREL, and thus it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 17):

Using pure Arel (not Rails/ActiveRecord) there is a "distinct" method:

```ruby
Arel::VERSION # => '3.0.2'
posts = Arel::Table.new(:posts)
posts.project(posts[:title])
posts.distinct
posts.to_sql # => 'SELECT DISTINCT "posts"."title" FROM "posts"'
```

Curiously, the "distinct" method is not chainable, per the other Arel methods.

Comment: With Arel version, `5.0.1`, this no longer works :(.

Comment: Arel 6, everything works perfectly. It's also chainable, as it's returning SelectManager.

Comment: arel 6.0.3 and this saved my day, though i used `distinct_on`

Answer (score 15):

The Arel way to do it is:

```
t = Arel::Table.new(:foo)
count_distinct = t[:field].count(true)
count_distinct.to_sql # => "COUNT(DISTINCT `foo`.`field`)"
```

Comment: This doesn't strictly answer the question but it does happen to answer _my_ question: how do you express `count(DISTINCT attr)` using Arel.

Answer (score 7):

The previous answer is the Rails way, no?  Not the Arel way.

This works for [arel](/questions/tagged/arel) 1.x:

```
posts = Table(:posts)
posts.project(Arel::Distinct.new(posts[:title]))
```

I'd guess there's another "more correct" way to do this via the API but I haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: This is true.  This answer was for Arel 1.x and will no longer work.

Comment: Do you know what's the alternative?

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this using a scope:

```
  scope :recent, lambda {|count|
    select("DISTINCT posts.*").
    joins(:whatever).
    limit(count).
    order("posts.updated_at DESC")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since AREL always uses SET in it's operation, duplicate row results will be deleted automatically. Just use a normal Project (Phi) operation.

Comment: This is a nice idea in theory but it is patently false in reality.  Arel queries will return duplicate entries from any projection unless constrained by the "distinct" method explicitly.